# Is it possible to track session duration for each user on Google Analytics?

Tags: session, google-analytics, analytics

I'm using Google Analytics to track user behavior. In order to get actionable insights, one thing I have to track is the session duration for users. Is it possible to track session duration for each user on Google Analytics by sending user-id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the [User Explorer Report](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/6339208?hl=en) of GA you get an individual view of each user and the actions that he conducted on your website from the time of acquisition to the point of exist and at times to when the user comes back.

Answer (score 0):

[about the user id feature](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3123662?hl=en)

> User ID lets you associate a persistent ID for a single user with that user's engagement data from one or more sessions initiated from one or more devices.
>
> Analytics interprets each unique user ID as a separate user, which provides a more accurate user count in your reports.

So setting [user id](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/cookies-user-id#user_id) is an internal field used by google for processing of your data.  This is not a field you will be able to see so it will be hard for you to analytics things based upon this user id.

However you could send the userid with all the calls as a [custom dimension](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/custom-dims-mets) this will enable you to add the dimension to your reports.